# MySQL Is UUID() is evaluated only once in a statement?

Tags: mysql, uuid

Consider this:

```
select uuid() from my_table;
```

returns different UUIDs:

```
"fc28ee4e-a147-11e8-93aa-0242ac120002"
"fc28ee7d-a147-11e8-93aa-0242ac120002"
"fc28ee84-a147-11e8-93aa-0242ac120002"
"fc28ee8c-a147-11e8-93aa-0242ac120002"
"fc28ee9b-a147-11e8-93aa-0242ac120002"
```

but

```
select replace (uuid(), '-', '') from my_table;
```

returns the same UUID:

```
"38d37436a14811e893aa0242ac120002"
"38d37436a14811e893aa0242ac120002"
"38d37436a14811e893aa0242ac120002"
"38d37436a14811e893aa0242ac120002"
"38d37436a14811e893aa0242ac120002"
```

**Why is the UUID the same in the replace function ?**

I stumbled upon this problem when trying to insert rows with a single statement, using UUIDs as primary key and I got a duplicate key error.

```
INSERT INTO my_Table (id, updated_at)
SELECT unhex(replace (uuid(), '-', '')), sysdate() FROM another_table
```

The weirdest thing is that the colleague who wrote this statement gets different UUIDs for each insert. How come ?

I tried with HeidiSQL and PhpMyAdmin.

Version info:

```
"innodb_version"    "5.7.21"
"protocol_version"  "10"
"slave_type_conversions"    ""
"tls_version"   "TLSv1,TLSv1.1"
"version"   "5.7.21"
"version_comment"   "MySQL Community Server (GPL)"
"version_compile_machine"   "x86_64"
"version_compile_os"    "Linux"
```

**Ugly workaround**

Instead of replace, use concat of several substrings:

```
SELECT unhex(concat(substring(uuid(), 1, 8), substring(uuid(), 10, 4), substring(uuid(), 15, 4), substring(uuid(), 20, 4), substring(uuid(), 25, 12)))
```

This works, but the generated ID is not unique anymore. So the culprit really seems to be the REPLACE function. I still would like to understand the initial problem.

Comment: This is weird because I'm now also getting different UUIDs with `REPLACE`.

Comment: For bonus weirdness points, I'm getting same UUID's with `UNHEX(REPLACE(...))`, but different ones with a custom function which has the same `UNHEX(REPLACE(...))` inside it.

Comment: I added a workaround. Still, I am puzzled...

Comment: Btw, for PK purposes it is better to swap the bytes around, so the first ones are the ones that don't change. MySQL's native [UUID_TO_BIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-to-bin) has an option for that, unfortunately it doesn't yet exist in your version.

Comment: if you want integer universal id then use **select uuid_short()**

Comment: FWIW, I can't replicate this behaviour either.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem today (MySQL 5.7) and found an old article (2005) about it. And it seems to be the collation for me

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-names.html

Using

```
set names utf8;
```

helped my script.

Used the following to test uniqueness

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u)
FROM (SELECT uuid() as u from my_table) as A
```